# Windows 10 doesn't boot in grub saying "error cannot load image"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a laptop with two disks on it. One has Windows 10 and the other has Ubuntu.It automatically boots through Windows but when i change the order to boot through Ubuntu and get brought to Grub Ubuntu loads fine but when i hit enter on Windows 10 i get an error saying something like:

/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,if)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,1f4.....
error: cannot load image

So i then came on here and saw a question similar to my problem and the answer was to go to the terminal and type:

sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom

then type this in the editor:

menuentry Windows 10 (disk 1) {

set root=(hd0,msdos1)

chainloader +1

boot

}

Then Hit Ctrl+O and then ENTER. HitCtrl+X. Now run:

sudo update-grub

That made another menu option in Grub called Windows and when i hit enter on the new menu option i get a new error saying:

error: disk `hd0,msdos1' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Is what i typed in the terminal relevant to my problem and do i need to adjust it slightly or is it completely irrelevant and i should delete it and if so what should i do instead? thanks.

Also i cannot access any file that are saved in windows when i'm on Ubuntu, i have to boot through Windows if i want to access my files.